# Remove all author names from yoast meta

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using yoast seo in my wordpress, and it is show the author name in source code if i am activated sharing feature,

```
<meta name="author" content="USERNAME" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<script type="application/ld+json" class="yoast-schema-graph">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@graph":[{"@type":"Article","@id":"","isPartOf":{"@id":""},"author":{"name":"USERNAME","@id":""}
```

I used this code but it not working

```
function remove_author( $authors ) {
return array_map( function( $author ) {
if ( ! $author instanceof Meta_Author_Presenter ) {
return $author;
}
}, $authors );
}

add_action( 'wpseo_frontend_presenters', 'remove_author' );
```

If i disabled Open Graph data & Twitter card data it will remove the first meta name author but it will be still in , and i need it open because if fix sharing on social media problems.

Any help please?